# Getting mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0' when exporting database though shell in MAMP

Tags: mysql, terminal, mamp

I am trying to export a database in mysql from Mac terminal using

```
 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -u root -p databasename tablename > /Users/mir/Documents/data.sql
```

It's giving me an error  **mysqldump: [ERROR] unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'**

I have tried many solutions like 
(i) adding "--column-statistics=0" in the query itself and
(ii) adding

```
[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0
```

in my.cnf at /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf.

Nothing solve the issue.
Looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Find your my.cnf file using command in terminal "locate my.cnf"
My case I put

```
[mysqldump]
column-statistics=0
```

in  /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf to solve the issue.

Comment: In fact the line should be there and that's the reason why you're getting this error. Remove or comment (#) the line.

Comment: When I did that and ran `php artisan schema:dump --database=mysql_testing` I got into a loop showing `mysqldump: unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'` until it ran out of memory.